# Brine added made sauerkraut too salty

Tags: fermentation

I make my sauerkraut in a big crock. I do about 20-30lbs at a time. I usually can it, but this time I just wanted to pack in jars and put in fridge. Unfortunately I didn't have enough brine in the original batch so I had to add more to each jar. Now the good sauerkraut I made is really salty. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice SE. :) Doesn't the cabbage "cure" in salt? Can you give us more information about what was different between the first batch of brine, and the second? Also... is the sauerkraut finished, or still in progress?

Comment: Very fresh Sauerkraut must be salty. It turns sour during the fermentation process. Maybe the fermentation takes longer this time because there are less beneficial bacteria in the fresh brine.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that your brine, and the resulting kraut is too salty, once your kraut is fermented, you can rinse it before you use it.  In fact, there are recipes for sauerkraut (Julia Child's choucroute garni comes to mind), that rinses the kraut several times before braising.